# SQL GOTO statement using variable label

Tags: sql, sql-server, goto

i was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
declare @label varchar
set @label = 'label_1'
goto @label

label_1:

label_2:
```

of course, sql server gives me an incorrect syntax error... so i was wondering if i can still do this with a slightly different syntax?

Answer (score 5):

I've cooked up a functional hack that may prove useful to others. On SQL Server 2008, you cannot dynamically build the goto, nor can you supply the label in a variable. The old school hack is to load the variable, jump to a single point that then uses if statements to determine the real destination.

GOTOs are of course [**considered harmful**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Considered_harmful) and are generally a bad idea.

```
l1:
    print '1'
l2:
    print '2'
    goto l4
l3:
    print '3'   -- should not print
l4:
    print '4'
    declare @lbl nvarchar(5)
    set @lbl = N'l6'
    goto vjump
    --  goto @lbl   -- doesn't work
    --  exec('goto ' + @lbl) -- doesn't work
l5:
    print '5'
l6:
    print '6'
l7:
    print '7'
    return
vjump:
    if @lbl = 'l1'
        goto l1
    if @lbl = 'l2'
        goto l2
    if @lbl = 'l3'
        goto l3
    if @lbl = 'l6'
        goto l6
```

This produces

```
1
2
4
6
7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this if you dynamically build the SQL statement.

GOTOs are best avoided though - mainly for code readability.

Comment: I had a hard time understanding it, until I realized the whole SQL statement (with goto and all the labels) should be inside the dynamically built SQL statement. Not only the goto statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use an if/else?

Comment: If he's using SQL2k, probably is for error processing - as copying-paste all error processing in all necessary places is really worse than goto.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot parameterize GOTO. You can do that if you use Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Not a timely answer obviously, but when I recently found myself wanting to do this, the reason was because I wanted to execute the same bit of code multiple times and then return to the normal flow, basically "gosub" and not "goto"....

And **that** you can do.  Not with a gosub, but with a temporary stored procedure -- create a temp stored procedure `create procedure #DRY` and then call it.  You can drop it when you are done.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
exec("goto "+@label)
```